# how to change double to string with digit grouping (1000000 to 1,000,000 )?

Tags: android

I have some double number ( lets say 1000000 ) and i want to cast this double to string but with digit grouping ( need to be 1,000,000 )

how to do it on android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NumberFormat` to format using a Locale:

```
NumberFormat df = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);

String myNumber = df.format(myNumber);
```